# MVC App Deployed to Azure - Do I have to use SQL Server Azure

Tags: azure

I am completely new to Microsoft Azure. I have just about completed an MVC 5 application that uses SQL Server 2012. I'd ilke to deploy my app to Azure but have it hit a SQL Server 2012 database that is hosted someone else (another commercial web host). Is this possible, or do I have to use SQL Azure for my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use another vendor but you'll have to check if they allow outside traffic in (usually on port 1433).  Even if they allow this, you'll have to think about the possible latency issue caused by such an architecture.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think outside traffic is going to be a problem because I can connect to my database on their site via my local copy of SSMS. And I can run my app locally and hit the DB on their site. Latency could be an issue but it might be a desirable exchange for not having to pay to use SQL Azure.

Comment: Note that you'll also pay data egress charges for Azure if you use this setup as your DB connection will traverse the Internet and will be treated as external data.